# Aliens destroy Earth. Book follows humanity's rebirth after attack

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the title of a book I read about 30 years ago. I think it was a YA science fiction book.

Earth and nearly all life had been destroyed by an alien weapon. Few remaining humans were underground when the weapon went off. One was a scientist with his children and in his lab were bees and rabbits.

Over the different parts of the book, you watch as humanity and earth recovers. Bees and rabbits are the primary food source.

Fast forward and family groups live in fertile valleys. When the girls come of age, they are required to leave and find a valley that will accept them. This section follows a girl on this journey.

Fast forward, humans have evolved a variety of telekenetic / psychic powers and have learned who destroyed the planet centuries before. These aliens have been "managing" humans since the destruction.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 6):

This is "Strange Tomorrow" by Jean E. Karl. The main characters in both stories are named Janie. The second is named after the first. Earth was attacked by Clord.  The sequel is The "Turning Point", which is about 15 stories of Post-Clordian humans.

Comment: THANK YOU so very much!!!! I have looked for this title for a couple of years now!!!

Comment: You're welcome!